# How can I proxypass a port range on nginx?

Tags: node.js, nginx

My Node.js server by default listens on port 5000 and can be accessed using localhost:5000.  I have my nginx server pass any requests to the server using the following config:

```
server {

        root /var/www/example.com/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
                proxy_http_version 1.1;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

        }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = www.example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        server_name example.com www.example.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot




}
```

This works for the most part, except when I redirect to a different port.  Later on I call res.redirect('localhost:5001/user') for instance which causes nginx to just hang.  It doesn't seem to be able to connect to any other port than 5000.  How can I set up my nginx server to accept redirects for a port range other than 5000?

I tried to replace 5000 with $server_port, but that doesn't seem to work out either.

Answer (score -1):

So what I got from question is you want NGINX to respond to other ports as well.

You can have something of this sort. If you want range of ports, this is not possible for NGINX to provide range of ports. If you want NGINX to listen on 1000 different ports, you will have to explicitly mention 1000 different listen statements in NGINX config file as follows:

```
listen 5001;
listen 443;
listen ...;
listen ...;
listen ...;
```

Comment: How do I get it to proxy the request to the correct port though?  The proxy always passes localhost:5000, regardless of whatever the port.

Comment: Ok. So you should have similar `server{...}` blocks and you can `listen` on different ports and as per your convenience, you can `proxy_pass to different ports`